# Need search function to navigate to last line in continuous occurrence range

Tags: search, motion, navigation

I am looking for a way to improve searching by repeating pattern.
Let's say some program prints lots of log messages with the same pattern:

```
copying path '/nix/store/lqfjx7x6imy5a9xab1ff5nhg90v089rq-postgresql-12.8' from 'https://cache.nixos.org'...
copying path '/nix/store/i80hgssxz2710ysawck5k9im6ccbic89-postgresql-13.4' from 'https://cache.nixos.org'...
copying path '/nix/store/qnq00zsw837kiyhvi3jxcizw0gim5g6f-util-linux-2.36.2-bin' from 'https://cache.nixos.org'...
copying path '/nix/store/kr4w1cjjcy4ml7wpb5x6i8dbivdx36rh-postgresql-libpq-0.9.4.3' from 'https://cache.nixos.org'...
```

Cursor is on a line starting with `copying path` and my goal is to jump to the nearest line above/below containing `copying path`; meanwhile neighbor line doesn't have matching pattern.

Such a function and shortcut would boost navigation performance across shell buffer. I hope the library I am interested in exists.

Comment: Doesn't `isearch-forward` or `isearch-backward` work for this? They are bound to `C-s` and `C-r` resp. and you can give it the pattern the first time. After that each `C-s` or `C-r` searches for the same pattern in the indicated direction. Although the description in the title and the description in the body of the question seem different to me. Maybe you can clarify by editing the question?

Comment: Standard search forward/backward has no sense because it moves cursor just to next line, because pattern is found on closest hundreds of lines. I need to jump the border between lines where pattern matches and doesn't match.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Consider using `M-x keep-lines`, to just (at least temporarily) remove the lines that don't start that way. Use `undo` to restore them, if you need them later. Or work with a copy of the text, where you don't mind deleting the uninteresting lines.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how you would like this function to work exactly, but it sounds like you can achieve it with only a few lines of code, e.g. the following:

```
(defun my-jump-to-non-matching-line (arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((regexp (if arg
                    (thing-at-point 'word t)
                  (read-string "Jump to first line not matching regexp: "))))
    (while (and (string-match regexp (thing-at-point 'line))
                (not (eobp)))
      (forward-line))))
```

You can simply do `M-x my-jump-to-non-matching-line` and enter some (part of the repeating) pattern that is not contained in the line where you would like to jump to.
By doing `C-u M-x my-jump-to-non-matching-line`, the function automatically uses the word under the cursor as pattern (in your example, for example, place the cursor on 'copying' and press `C-u M-x my-jump-to-non-matching-line`).

Of course, you can also create a keybinding for this command.

Finally, you can make a `search-backward` version by changing `eobp` to `bobp` and adding a `-1` behind `forward-line`.